# Limit CPU usable by specific program?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, adobe-flash

I'm having issues running Flash JSFL scripts. I believe this is because they are literally running too fast on my modern processor, so Flash CS6 is tripping over itself again and again when trying to run them. These specific scripts do not work in modern versions due to unsupported features (I tried in Adobe Animate 2023).

Is there a way I can limit the speed of instructions that a program can run? I've tried using 'set affinity' in task manager, to limit to a single core, but even the single-core performance is too fast.

Comment: https://mion.yosei.fi/BES/ & https://windowsreport.com/limit-cpu-usage/